# How do you build a slide-up panel in React Native, which slides up after you click a button?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

See image below to see example - when you click the button, the pane should slide up, and you can then close it by clicking into the map, or sliding it back down.

[image: Click here for image]

Comment: pretty good extension for sliding up panel component https://github.com/octopitus/rn-sliding-up-panel

Answer (score 3):

Used github.com/octopitus/rn-sliding-up-panel to solve this.